# Nexus 6P wrong time

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, nexus-6p

Whilst in my pocket, I have pulled out my Nexus 6P and found it has rebooted (at least this is what I assume as it now wants my full passcode and will not allow unlock with fingerprint).

I also find that the time is wrong. It has reset back to 1st Jan 1970 12am. I have not been able to get it to correct itself (via my network - EE in UK if that matters).

The only fix has been to disable automatic time sync, manually set it, and then re-enable auto time sync.

How can I get this to auto rectify the issue next time it happens? Its very annoying!

I am fully up-to-date with all software and patches.

Comment: usually this happens when a non system app tries to get date before system connects to network after a flash or reboot(always happens with whatsapp).Hence manual checking/unchecking or re-reboot works. try to stop apps staring at boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this keeps repeating it may probably be an firmware level problem. In that case you can try flashing the Nexus 6p ROM image available from Google Android site(provided your phone's bootloader is unlocked) . 
There is a fair chance of it being a hardware issue as well. If so, better get it checked from an authorized service center. Even if it is just a software glitch, if your phone is under warranty and you haven't unlocked /rooted it, take it to the service guys. That way your warranty won't get void

Comment: Thanks for the response. Hasn't happened since I posted that, so I'll wait until the next incident. I am also having serious on/off performance issues that may be related so I will look to get that resolved too.